# Azure Devops pipelines that target a specific environment

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, azure-pipelines

I have two ADO pipelines one is CI and CD and they are running when CI is completed CD automatically getting triggered without any issues.

My requirement is I have 3 environments in CI and CD jobs like dev stg and itg
I want to deploy my CD job based on environments selections automatically when CI completed.

lets say when I trigger CI job with Dev stack and once CI completed with Dev stack , CD should get triggered dev stack.
similarly for CI -itg selected once done CD- itg stack should be done automatically.

is there any way to link this two pipelines to get triggered based on environments selections.

Note : by default dev stack is working fine between CI and CD, but when I select itg in CI job and as soon as CI-itg completed , in CD job dev running not itg.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requiremnt, you need to trigger the CD Pipeline stage based on the CI Pipeline stage running.

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can achieve this requirement.

For a workaround, I suggest that you can manaully define the variable in Release Pipeline and you can modify the release pipeline variable in CI pipeline via Rest API:[Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) .

Refer to the following steps:

Step1: Define Release Pipeline variable.

[image]

Step2: Add a step to run PowerShell script in CI pipeline to each stage. When the Pipeline stage run, it will modify the value in Relase Pipeline.

For example:

```
stages:
  - stage: Dev
    jobs:
      - job: A 
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1"
                
                Write-Host "URL: $url"
                $pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{
                    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
                }
                Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
                
                # Update an existing variable named TestVar to its new value 2
                $pipeline.variables.Dev.value = "Yes"
                
                ####****************** update the modified object **************************
                $json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
                
                $updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
                
                write-host "==========================================================" 
                Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'Dev' is updated to" $updatedef.variables.Dev.value


  - stage: Stg
    jobs:
      - job: B 
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1"
                
                Write-Host "URL: $url"
                $pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{
                    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
                }
                Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
                
                # Update an existing variable named TestVar to its new value 2
                $pipeline.variables.stg .value = "Yes"
                
                ####****************** update the modified object **************************
                $json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
                
                $updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
                
                write-host "==========================================================" 
                Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'stg ' is updated to" $updatedef.variables.stg .value
```

Step3: In Release Pipeline stage, you can set the condition:`eq(variables['dev'], 'Yes')`

For example:

[image]